# read and split information from text file python

Tags: python

I'm stuck on a problem:

I have a text file called id_numbers.txt that contains this information:

```
325255, Jan Jansen

334343, Erik Materus

235434, Ali Ahson

645345, Eva Versteeg

534545, Jan de Wilde

345355, Henk de Vries
```

I need python to split the information at the comma and write a program that will the display the information as follows:

```
Jan Jansen has cardnumber: 325255

Erik Materus has cardnumber: 334343

Ali Ahson  has cardnumber: 235434

Eva Versteeg has cardnumber: 645345
```

I've tried to convert to list and `split(",")` but that ends up adding the next number like this:

```
['325255', ' Jan Jansen\n334343', ' Erik Materus\n235434', ' Ali Ahson\n645345', ' Eva Versteeg\n534545', ' Jan de Wilde\n345355', ' Henk de Vries']
```

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your whole example code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
with open('id_numbers.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip() # this removes the \n at the end
        id_num, name = line.split(',')
        name = name.strip() # in case name has trailing spaces in both sides
        print('{0} has cardnumber: {1}'.format(name, id_num))
```

Comment: `lines = f.readlines()` is redundant. Just do `for line in f`.

Comment: Keep in mind that `name` (the second part of the list) will have an extra whitespace at the beginning (the original data has whitespace after a comma).

Comment: i will fix that too

Comment: do lstrip() on name

Comment: Now the first `line.rstrip()` is redundant as you're removing both the leading and the trailing whitespace with `name.strip()`. ;)

Comment: Is this python 3.0? It works perfectly but I was just curious as it doesn't look like python code I recognize! Thanks anyway!

Comment: `f'{name} has card number: {id_num}'` for python3.6+

Comment: @Joshua - Can be both. In Python 3.x `print` is a function, not a statement but having some extra (redundant) brackets around `print` arguments on Python 2.x is perfectly OK. [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) exists in Python since 2.6 and [context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) (`with...`) exist since 2.5.

Comment: By the way Atul, no need for so many lines. can just do `id_num, name = line.strip().split(',')` and `'{0} has cardnumber: {1}'.format(name.strip(), id_num)`

Comment: Yeah I know that, I tried to keep the code as readable as possible